# Vue 2, How to do Static Data Declaration inside component

Tags: vuejs2, deployment, frontend

```
data() {
    return {
      tableHeaders: [{name: "uma"}]
    };
  },
```

let assume tableHeaders im using in template to display something.

But is it necessary to decalre tableHeaders inside data property (because, i dont need tableHeaders as reactive property. it will be always static). so any alternative for this?

because of the vue less restrictness, almost all data we will declare in data property only as state variable (is this is good approach?).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set and use static data in a Vue's component is to define this in created() hook:

```
<script>
export default {
// name, data() and other component's staff
        
created() {
  this.tableHeaders = [
    {name: 'uma'}
    {name: 'other one uma'}
  ]
}
};
</script>
```

Now you can use it in component's template:

```
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in tableHeaders" :key="item">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
</template>
```

Or use it in component's methods:

```
methods: {
    getTableHeaders: function() {
      return this.tableHeaders
    }
}
```